# Send Spring model to Freemarker head tag with no specific route

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm having a problem with sending from Spring to Freemarker. I'm using a service where I need to get script from calling a method and put the script in head tag. I'm using the same header.ftl for all the pages. That is, my head.ftl is something like:

```
<html>
<head>
   // head content
</head>
<body> // But no close tag for body.
```

In other ftl, I will do:

```
<#include "header.ftl">
// then continue with body content
```

This is what I'm doing:

In the UI controller that handles multiple RequestMappings, I add:

```
@ModelAttribute("client")
public Client getTheClient() {
    return new Client();
}
```

Other methods in this UI controller are mostly:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/apple")
public void apple(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
  // bind the page with a "apple.ftl" templage
}
```

In the head tag, I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">${client.getScript()}</script>
```

But it cannot find "client". (Says undefined or something)
Then I add

```
<#import "/spring.ftl as spring">
<@spring.bind "client">
```

before the script, now it says "Error reading imported spring.ftl". (I don't know where is spring.ftl either. I just follow other posts on the internet.)

Other posts are talking about giving a specific route to RequestMapping, and mostly uses jsp for frontend. But in my case it's different.

Can anyone help? I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `Client` object looks likes, could be helpful to post your model as well.

However, here are couple things I spotted:

**First**, every controller needs url mapping. Add one to your `getTheClient()` one:

```
@RequestMapping("/client/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getTheClient() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
    mav.addObject("client", new Client());

    return mav;
}
```

**Second**, your way of referencing the model an accessing it is incorrect. The correct way

```
<script type="text/javascript">${client.name}</script>
```

Assuming model name is `Client`, and the field is `name` (no need to use set or get prefexes).